# How to cache a HTML page with must-revalidate?

Tags: caching, http-headers, browser-cache, etag, last-modified

When caching a HTML page with `must-revalidate`, this means that browser must check for any update defined by `Last-Modified` or `Etag`. However, the problem is that before `max-age`, browser will not make any connection with the website to read HTTP headers (to analyze `Last-Modified` and `Etag`)?

How to force the browser to make a brief connection to read (at least) HTTP readers before loading the page from cache?

I do not understand the usage of `must-revalidate`! Doesn't it its responsibility to check for updates before `max-age`? because after reaching `max-age`, browser will read from the website and never use local cache.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of `must-revalidate` is wrong: it says that the cache may not serve this content when it is *stale* (i.e. "expired"), but must revalidate before that. Yes, caches (and browsers) can in theory be set to serve pages even if they are stale, though the standard says they should warn the user if they do this.

To force the browser to recheck your page with the server, the simplest solution is to add `max-age=0` to the `Cache-Control` header. This will let your browser keep a copy of the page in its cache, but compare it with the server's version by sending the contents of `Last-Modified` or `ETag`, as you wanted.

It used to be that you could add `no-cache` instead, but as users have been expecting this to behave as `no-store`, browsers are gradually treating them the same.

Check the [HTTP/1.1 RFC, section 14.9](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) for more information on the headers.

Comment: very useful infromation and practical guide, but I did not understand one thing. You said "the cache may NOT serve this content when it is expired, but must revalidate before that". In any case, even without `must-revalidate`, cache will NOT be served when expired.

Comment: If you reread the end of 14.9.3 in the RFC above, it mentions that not only can caches be configured to serve stale responses, clients (browsers) could use `max-stale` to indicate that a stale response is fine. It also mentions that a `Warning` header must be attached, though.